# Getting hold of web3 from inside a Truffle JS test

Tags: web3js, truffle

How do I access a `web3` instance from inside a Truffle Javascript test?

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that Truffle automatically injects web3 into the Javascript test file. Simply use it directly as follows:

```
//  test/mycontract.js

...

contract("MyContract", accounts => {
  var accountA = accounts[0];

  it("...should...", async () => {

    const accountABalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accountA);

    ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

At the top of your truffle .js file you can write:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:9545'));
```

And in one of your `it` test blocks, you can then use `web3.[desired func]`.

Comment: Thanks! But it turns out Truffle automatically injects web3.