# Why don't we have to import web3.js into testing js files?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, test

As a newbie to solidity, this is my code for testing some smart contract that I wrote, by
following a tutorial. The name of the file is "EthSwap.test.js" and I'm using "truffle".

```
const { assert } = require("chai");

const Token = artifacts.require("Token");
const EthSwap = artifacts.require("EthSwap");

require("chai")
  .use(require("chai-as-promised"))
  .should();

function tokens(n) {
  return web3.utils.toWei(n, "ether");
}

contract("EthSwap Smart Contract", (accounts) => {
  var ethSwap, token;
  before(async () => {
    ethSwap = await EthSwap.new();
    token = await Token.new();
    await token.transfer(ethSwap.address, tokens('1000000'));
  });

  it("contract has tokens", async () => {
    const balance = await token.balanceOf(ethSwap.address);
    assert.equal(balance.toString(),  tokens('1000000'));
  });
});
```

It passed the test well. But I wonder why we don't have to import web3.js into this test file. We can just use it in the "tokens(n)" function without importing it to the file. How does it happen?? someone please help me to understand it...

Comment: Truffle injects automatically web3, when you run `truffle test`. You would want to import explicitly if you run your tests with external commands, like `node` or something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting hold of web3 from inside a Truffle JS test](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58482/getting-hold-of-web3-from-inside-a-truffle-js-test)

Comment: @gneric That's an easy explanation. Thank you so much. I think I don't have to delete this question since I couldn't find a similar question.